# Unable to return Account Linking button from Amazon Lex to FB Messenger

Tags: facebook, messenger, amazon-lex

Im developing a FB chatbot using Lex. To integrate the user experience Im trying to match the user on my DB (UID of User) to the user chatting on Lex ( PSID ). I have been suggested to use AccountLinking API to achieve this.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking/v2.9

In the API they have asked to request a button with type="account_link". How ever the lex bot doesnt allow to place a key "type" in the response card and throws an error when done.

1. Firstly am I on the right track.?
2. If yes, Is there a way to make lex accept the key-parameter "type" ?

I have come across ID-Matching API aswell but I would like to know the expected way solving the problem (Not shortcuts which may break in near future ).